# sorting a part of a array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a problem with sorting of arrays in PHP.
I tried all the sort functions in PHP but no one of them can sort only parts of a array.
 How can i only sort a part of an array in PHP?

As an sample, i have a array like this:

```
$letter = array("n", "a", "s", "c", "b", "m", "z", "o")
```

Now i whant only sort from the element 2 until the element 6 of my array.

This means, in the result, the array must be sortet like this:
n, a, b, c, m, s, z, o.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks, 
Nico

Comment: You must try this on your own before asking here.

Comment: Split the array from element 2 to element 6, and enter it into new array. Then the sort the new array and merge them...

Comment: We won't code for you. Please show some effort (code; research; pseudo code)

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you, i will have a look and will try it with array_slice() and array_splice()

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry than you have misunderstood me! I never have ask or want that you or other users code for me, i have only ask, to find a way to fix my problem. I think StackOverflow is a platform where users can ask for help (in this case like me) and users where can help, like MarkBaker.

Comment: @Nico Stack Overflow doesn't provide links to resources, it's one of the reasons for closing a question. It expects you to have written some code, and if it doesn't work we'll help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

extract elements 2-6 using [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), then re-insert using [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$letter = array("n", "a", "s", "c", "b", "m", "z", "o");

$start = 2;
$end = 6;

$temp = array_slice($letter, $start-1, $end-$start);
sort($temp);
array_splice($letter, $start-1, $end-$start, $temp);
var_dump($letter);
```

Note the `$start` adjustment as you're counting from element 1, whereas PHP enumerated arrays start from 0

Comment: Always love explanation with the function names build into the sentence :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to split your array up, take the first and last elements and store them separately before sorting the array and then adding them back in. The commands you'll need are [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to remove the first and last elements, then [`array_unshift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) and [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to add them back in.

Try this:

```
$letter = array("n", "a", "s", "c", "b", "m", "z", "o");
$first = array_shift($letter);
$last = array_pop($letter);
asort($letter);
array_unshift($letter, $first);
array_push($last);
```

If it's just the 2nd to 6th elements you want to sort regardless of the length of the array then you will need something like this:

```
$letter = array("n", "a", "s", "c", "b", "m", "z", "o");
$to_sort = array_splice($letter, 1, 6);
sort($to_sort);
array_splice($letter, 1, 0, $to_sort);
```

Here's an eval.in example to show it working: https://eval.in/353847

Comment: Let's all hope OP will always have the same amount of elements in the array.

Comment: @Rizier123 it's only the first and last he doesn't want sorted. This will do that regardless of the number of elements in the array, but I'll add an `array_splice()` options as well if it's always the 2nd to 6th elements he wants, regardless of the number in the array.